# VBA: subroutine with if statement and returning true or false?

Tags: vba, excel, subroutine

***SOLVED!***

I have to validate that certain cells are not empty, so I want to create a subroutine and pass the variables I need checked.

This is what I came up with:

```
Sub errorMessage(errMsg As String, errRange As String)
If Range(errRange) = "" Then
    MsgBox errMsg, , "Error:"
    Range(errRange).Activate
    'this is what i was looking for :doh:, the 'end' line terminates everything..
    END
End Sub
```

Now when I call it from my button, will it actuall end the sub of the button?

i.e.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Call errorMessage("name is missing", "D4")

    'this function shouldn't be called if there was a msgbox displayed with the above call 
sendEmail 


End Sub
```

How can i make this happen?

***EDIT:***

OK So this is how i sovled it, the reason i'm trying to do this is to avoid tons of lines of code in the buttonClick sub, what are your thoughts??

keep in mind that this thing has to check about 25 questions for blanks before executing the sendEmail sub....

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


    Call validateEntry("Client Name is missing.", "D4")
    Call validateEntry("# not complete.", "D5")


    Call validateEntry("Address same as CV?", "D6")


    Call validateEntry("Number missing.", "D8")
    Call validateEntry("Type missing.", "D9")
    Call validateEntry("Q1 requires a Yes or No.", "E19")
    Call validateEntry("Q2 requires a Yes or No.", "E21")
    Call validateEntry("Q3 requires a Yes or No.", "E23")
    Call validateEntry("Q4 requires a Yes or No.", "E25")
    Call validateEntry("Q5 requires a Date.", "D28")
    Call validateEntry("Q6 requires a Yes or No.", "E30")
    Call validateEntry("Q7 requires a Yes or No.", "E32")



MsgBox "passed"
'sendEmail
End Sub


Sub validateEntry(errMsg As String, errRange As String)
    If Range(errRange) = "" Then
        MsgBox errMsg, , "Error:"
        Range(errRange).Activate
        End
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Using `End` is a **really** bad idea, see [here](http://vbcity.com/forums/t/96612.aspx).  There is absolutely no object clean-up when using `End`.

Answer (score 2):

So, in your example, you're looking for the "passed" notification to only be sent when there is data in cell D4, right?

This should work:

```
Private Function errorMessage(errMsg As String, errRange As String) As Boolean
    errorMessage = False

    If Len(Trim(Range(errRange))) = 0 Then
        MsgBox errMsg, , "Error:"
        Range(errRange).Activate

        errorMessage = True
    End If
End Function

Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If errorMessage("name is missing", "D4") = False Then
        MsgBox "passed"
    End If
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you can handle all MsgBox notifications from within the function, to group similar logic together, and keep the Button Click Event Sub clean:

```
Private Function errorMessage(errMsg As String, errRange As String)
    If Len(Trim(Range(errRange))) = 0 Then
        MsgBox errMsg, , "Error:"
        Range(errRange).Activate
    Else
        MsgBox "passed"
    End If
End Function

Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call errorMessage("name is missing", "D4")
End Sub
```

Comment: what i'm looking for is to end the buttonclick function if the errorMessage call displays the msgbox;  this way i can avoid having the buttonclick function execute the send email code if there was an error...

Comment: Ok figured it out, i can do it by using 'End' in the if statement, boy do i feel dumb!

Comment: Don't use `End`! See @LittleBobbyTables answer. Use `Exit Sub`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of misconceptions here.

First, no, it will not end the button routine by default.  You will need to handle that within your button.

Next, you're missing an `End If` somewhere in here:

```
Sub errorMessage(errMsg As String, errRange As String)
    If Range(errRange) = "" Then  ' This may not be the best way to check for 
                                  ' an empty range
        MsgBox errMsg, , "Error:"
        Range(errRange).Activate
        Exit Sub
End Sub
```

You really don't even want a subroutine in the first place, you want a function that returns a boolean, like this:

```
Function errorMessage(errMsg As String, errRange As String) as Boolean
    ' Function returns True if an error occured
    errorMessage = False
    If Range(errRange) = "" Then
        MsgBox errMsg, , "Error:"
        Range(errRange).Activate
        errorMessage = True
    End If
End Sub
```

And then here:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    If errorMessage("name is missing", "D4") Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'this msgbox should not display if the above msgbox is displayed
    MsgBox "passed"

    ' continue on with all of your fun processing here
End Sub
```

Comment: @maxgohan You tried to edit this post with a comment that you can't actually add an answer to your own question...but you can, and are encouraged to do so, if your answer solves your problem in a way that hasn't been presented as well or at all by another answer.

Comment: thanks @Beska, i've edited my original post with what works for me, please lmk what kind of issues that can happen if i do it this way.